# Skipping builds in codeship

Tags: codeship

I am reading the Codeship documentation about [skipping builds](https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-integration/skipping-builds/#stq=&stp=0).

I am struggling to understand the correct format when doing a commit. I want to skip builds because I don't want to go over the 100 free monthly builds. I will run the tests myself instead.

Codeship says that I can `--skip-ci` or `[skip ci]` to the commit message. I have tried formats like:

```
git commit -m "My message" --skip-ci
git commit -m "My message" [skip ci]
git commit -m -skip-ci "My message"
```

None of these work. What is the right format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct format is to add the method to the string itself:

```
git commit -m "My message --skip-ci"
```

or:

```
git commit -m "My message [skip ci]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a couple of handy aliases, extended from [Oh-My-Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). My workflow has been improved by adding these to my system;

Create a WIP commit:

`alias gwip='git add -A; git rm $(git ls-files --deleted) 2> /dev/null; git commit -m "--wip--"'`

And then create a WIP commit without running CI:

`alias gwipskip='git add -A; git rm $(git ls-files --deleted) 2> /dev/null; git commit -m "--wip-- --skip-ci"'`